# Random partitioner does not distribute messages between Kafka topic partitions

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I've created a topic in Kafka with 9 partitions, naming it aptly 'test', and knocked together two simple applications in C# (.NET Core), using `Confluent.Kafka` client library: a producer and a consumer. I did little more than tweak [examples from the documentation](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet).

I am running two instances of the consumer application and one instance of the producer. I don't see much point in pasting the consumer code here, it's a trivial 'get a message, print it on screen' app, however, it does also print the number of the partition the message came from.

This is the producer app:

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var random = new Random();

        var config = new ProducerConfig {
            BootstrapServers = "10.0.0.5:9092",
            Partitioner = Partitioner.ConsistentRandom
        };

        int counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            using (var p = new ProducerBuilder<string, string>(config).Build())
            {
                try
                {
                    p.BeginProduce(
                        "test",
                        new Message<string, string>
                        {
                            //Key = random.Next().ToString(),
                            Value = $"test {++counter}"
                        });

                    if (counter % 10 == 0)
                        p.Flush();
                }
                catch (ProduceException<Null, string> e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Delivery failed: {e.Error.Reason}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Problem:** If the `Key` property of the message is not set, all messages get sent to the partition number 7, meaning that one of my consumer instances is idle. I had to manually randomise the key in order to distribute them between partitions (see the commented out line). (The original code, as copied from the docs, used `Null` as the type of the key, and this sent all messages to the 7th partition too.)

Why  is that? According to the documentation of the `ProducerConfig.Partitioner` property, the `consistent_random` option should ensure random distribution if the key is not specified. I tried using the `Partioner.Random` option, which should use random distribution regardless of the key, but this did not help.

Is this the expected behaviour, am I doing something wrong, or did I come across a bug?

I am using version 1.0.0-RC2 of Confluent.Kafka NuGet.

Complete documentation of the Partitioner config:

```
// Summary:
//     Partitioner: `random` - random distribution, `consistent` - CRC32 hash of key
//     (Empty and NULL keys are mapped to single partition), `consistent_random` - CRC32
//     hash of key (Empty and NULL keys are randomly partitioned), `murmur2` - Java
//     Producer compatible Murmur2 hash of key (NULL keys are mapped to single partition),
//     `murmur2_random` - Java Producer compatible Murmur2 hash of key (NULL keys are
//     randomly partitioned. This is functionally equivalent to the default partitioner
//     in the Java Producer.). default: consistent_random importance: high
```

Comment: I don't think there would be a bug in the project.  Can you add the link to Partitioner config documentation?

Comment: @JRibkr Yeah, I don't really think it's a bug either, something so obvious would surely have been spotted. I copied the documentation from the XML docs in the library itself, as seen in Visual Studio, I don't know if an online version is available at all. A google search only yielded this source file: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/src/Confluent.Kafka/Config_gen.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue.
Seems like when initiating a client, the first message will always go the same partition.
The Partioner.Random will work if you use the same client for all your messages

Comment: I had the same problem, using `ProducerBuilder<Null, string>`, and setting `Partitioner = Partitioner.Random` didn't have any effect. All messages were produced to a single partition. @kamilk or @Ran Mansoor, do you have any working code you could share?